# What does the rending weapon property do?

Tags: warhammer-40k, only-war

We have weapons that have "rending" but we can't find out what rending does. Anyone know?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Rending* is **not** a special quality of a weapon. It is the weapon's *Damage Type* as introduced on page 168 under **Weapons**.

*Rending* is the kind of damage done by swords, blades and claws. In contrast to for example explosive damage, done by grenades, energy damage done by laser weapons or impact damage by bullets or falling from height.

On page 256 under the heading **Injury** and **Damage Types** the core rulebook states:

> The type of damage inflicted is usually only important for determining critical effects resulting from critical damage

So if you take critical damage from a weapon with the damage type of *Rending*, you consult the critical tables 8-19 through 8-22 on page 264 and 265 that say "rending critical effects".

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... it doesn't do anything for regular hits, but if it's a crit it determines what table to use.

Comment: Could you let us know which part of the rules describes this? A page reference and heading would help future visitors learn what's going on there. Imagine if they're just as oblivious as you were a few minutes ago, or just want to learn more. Or, heck, on that note: imagine what position you were in an hour ago. Someone giving you *this* answer probably would've been subpar and you'd have a lot of questions remaining. What would you want in that answer to make it excellent? Put that in this answer for others in your position in the future.

Comment: @doppelgreener Yeah, I would have loved to but unfortunately at the moment I found out I didn't have any of that information on me. Looks like nvoigt was able to share this info though so I marked his post as the answer.